# How to add two large numbers in SAS with precision?

Tags: sas

Suppose I have two large numbers: 5E31 and 8E34. Is there an easy way to add these numbers in SAS? I know these numbers may be too large for SAS but are there any shortcuts?

Comment: I only know the complicated way to add them by using java objects inside datastep

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add those two numbers; SAS can store numbers well over 8e34.  However, you cannot store *all 34 digits*; SAS uses IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers (on Windows/Linux) and can store up to *nearly* sixteen digits precisely (15 digits absolutely precisely).

See [Numerical Accuracy in SAS](http://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm) for more details about exactly how SAS stores numbers.  Also see [CONSTANT function documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0l7s11dwvzfq5n1wnw997dye8fx.htm) which shows how to get some of the values, such as the largest exact integer storable on your system.

If you do need that much precision, you need to either use another language (SAS can call Python or R in some versions depending on what you have licensed, for example), or you need to implement your own calculation engine based on strings or splitting the number into two pieces.  DS2 also has some options, but they're not storable in a SAS dataset, so they'd only be usable internally or in database/etc. systems that do understand more precise datatypes.

Comment: The large numbers are very close, for example -4.439319E31 + 4.4393187E31, but sometimes I get 0 when I add them up or sometimes I get  very large numbers such as 1E15 even though the original numbers are similar in magnitude. I expect the sum of the numbers to be in the 1000s since the original numbers are incredibly close.

Comment: You need to use `ROUND` like SAS mentions in the article above when doing math -and in particular, round *to the nearest `1e16`.  Since all of the digits after `1e16` are not significant, you want to discard them.

Comment: I tried the rounding but the sum of the numbers still don't seem to make sense. I know the numbers are very close but they are in E31. So even when rounding I am getting nonsensical answers when adding like 1E15. Its like saying 100 + -999 = 100000 but we know its 1.

Comment: Post a new question with example data and code and what you’re getting that doesn’t make sense. Then it will be easy for someone to help!

Comment: Okay going to do that